# iOS Continuously asks for sandbox IAP password

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

While testing my application iOS keeps asking for my sandbox IAP email and password. Is there a way to stop this? Even when testing features unrelated to IAP, I keep getting asked to login.

Seems like this should be more smooth for testing and such.

Anyway to fix this?

PS I'm using auto-renewable subscriptions in my application